# Laravel 5.3 pagination pretty URL for API

Tags: php, api, pagination, laravel-5.3

Is there a way to get a pagination pretty URL in Laravel 5.3?

For example, by default:

Search keyword is: `something new`

http://localhost/project/search/something%20new?page=2

```
{
  "total": 19,
  "per_page": 5,
  "current_page": 1,
  "last_page": 4,
  "next_page_url": "http://localhost/project/search/something%20new?page=2",
  "prev_page_url": null,
  "from": 1,
  "to": 5,
  "data": [
  {
     // result
    }
  ]
}
```

And what I would like to get:

```
http://localhost/project/search/?page=2
```

Also, the pagination should render this way, and appending to the pagination should appear in this way.

Controller.

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $search = $request->name;

    $searchValues = preg_split('/\s+/', $search, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    $result = abcModel::where( function ($q) use ($searchValues) {
        foreach ($searchValues as $value ) {
            $q->orWhere('city', 'like', "%{$value}%");
            $q->orWhere('country', 'like', "%{$value}%");
            $q->orWhere('name', 'like', "%{$value}%");
             } })
        ->orderby('id','desc')
        ->paginate(20);

    return response()->json( $result );
}
```

Route,

```
Route::post('search/',array('uses' => 'abcController@search'));
```

Request and Response is above..

Answer (score 1):

You would need to switch the HTTP method used for the search path to send the query string through POST instead of GET. So, without code posted I am assuming you have a route set up like this:

```
Route::get('project/search/{query}', 'ExampleController@search');
```

This would be changed to something like

```
Route::post('project/search/', 'ExampleController@search');
```

As long as you are handling the actual data with the Request object passed into the controller and maintain the same name in the POST body as the GET query parameter, there should be minimal modifications required to your code, if any are needed at all.

You could take it even further and handle the `page` parameter in the POST body as well, leaving your URL as `http://localhost/project/search/`.

Comment: Your updated route still has the search query as a GET parameter in the URL. You need to remove that. You also have the argument incorrect for your controller. Your function definition should be `public function search(Request $request)` and you retrieve values with the `input()` method of the `Request` class. Look at the documentation of the Request class here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests

Comment: once again check out my updated controller and routes, and its works.